When entire or meromorphic map of finite type restricts to a Galois covering?
Suppose that $f \colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is an entire map of finite type, i.e., with finitely many singular values. Then we can consider the restriction $f| \mathbb{C} \setminus f^{-1}(S_f) \colon \mathbb{C} \setminus f^{-1}(S_f) \to \mathbb{C} \setminus S_f$, where $S_f$ is the set of singular values of $f$. One can easily see that such a map is a covering map.
What are the maps $f$ for which this restriction is Galois, i.e., for any $w \in \mathbb{C} \setminus S_f$ and $z_1, z_2 \in f^{-1}(w)$, there exists a deck transformation $A \in \mathrm{Deck}(f) \subset \mathrm{Aut}^+(\mathbb{C})$ of $f$ such that $A(w_1) = w_2$? For instance, examples are $z \mapsto z^d$, $\exp(z), \cos(z)$, and, of course, the same maps but pre- and post-composed with complex-affine transformations. But is there anything else?
Of course, similar question can be formulated for meromorphic maps $f\colon \mathbb{C} \to \widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ and here we have family of examples produced by Weistrass elliptic functions. But one can ask again, is there anything else?

Essentially there is nothing else. Indeed, the group of deck transformations can be identified with a group of conformal automorphisms of the plane which acts discontinuously. There is a complete classification of such groups. In more modern terms this is phrased as classification of parabolic orbifolds. So, assuming that your $f$ is transcendental you have a) exponential, b) cosine, and c) three types of groups leading to elliptic functions. If your $f$ is rational, there is also a complete classification related to the groups of Platonic solids.
See, for example:
MR1251582 Douady, Adrien; Hubbard, John H. A proof of Thurston's topological characterization of rational functions. Acta Math. 171 (1993), no. 2, 263-297.
MR1027462 Eremenko, A. È. Some functional equations connected with the iteration of rational functions. (Russian) Algebra i Analiz 1 (1989), no. 4, 102–116; translation in Leningrad Math. J. 1 (1990), no. 4, 905–919.
MR3444841
Ford, Lester R.
Automorphic functions.
Second edition. Chelsea Publishing Co., New York, 1951. Chap. II, sect. II and III.
Remark. Your a priori restriction to "finite type" is not needed: there are no meromorphic functions in the plane which are infinite type and Galois coverings.
